# Cassandra Data modeling for Counter columns to be expirable

Tags: cassandra

I have an use-case where I am storing the data in a table with the counter columns. However the data stored in this table is few millions and I am trying to understand if there a way to expire this data automatically. I understand that cassandra [doesn't support TTL](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_using/useExpire.html) on the counter columns, so trying to evaluate if there are any other better ways to handle this, instead of running a job to purge the data.